# ImageResizer : FastScaling plugin error

Tags: imageresizer

I have this error, when I added the library 'ImageResizer.Plugins.FastScaling.DLL'

Error Message Analyzer: Could not load file or assembly 'ImageResizer.Plugins.FastScaling.DLL' or one of its dependencies . The specified module could not be found.

```html
Ligne 109 :                <add assembly="System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
Ligne 110 :                <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
Ligne 111 :                <add assembly="*" />
Ligne 112 :            </assemblies>  <!-- ERROR !!  -->
Ligne 113 :            <buildProviders>
```

I have the .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack installed and VS2015/VS2013 Cpp redist

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2015 if you are using IIS Express you need to set it to X64 mode.

Tools->Options -> Project and Solutions -> Web Projects -> "Check" "Use 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects"

Answer (score 4):

This typically occurs because you are using the x64 version of FastScaling in a 32-bit process, or vice versa.

Lacking the VC++ 2015 redistributable is another common cause.

Comment: I can't manage to make this work. I'm on x64 build setting project with x64 nuget dependency. Also Installed c++ 2015 redist x64 package. BadImageFormatException persists. Do we have a way to debug this?

Comment: btw. It runs on the server. Something wrong with Visual Studio I think.

Comment: Installing the VC++ 2015 redistributable did it for me. Also having IIS application pool with Enable 32-Bit set to false.